# bug using session and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

In login and register php functions I'm using this line:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

If in jquery function I use username as var the session changes and Im not using sessions on jquery functions

For example I have a feed burner so I have 2 records for the feed number and email.

Im using as:

```
var nombre = $('#nombre').val(); 
    var email = $('#email').val();

    $.post(global_data.url + 'files/assets/php/ajax/feed.php', 'nombre=' + nombre + '&email=' + email, function(a){
```

I'm not having problemas with the session but if I change nombre for username like this:

```
var username = $('#username').val(); 
    var email = $('#email').val();

    $.post(global_data.url + 'files/assets/php/ajax/feed.php', 'username=' + username + '&email=' + email, function(a){
```

The session changes

This is my feed.php code:

```
require('../../../inc/config.php');
require('../../../libs/Plantilla.class.php');
$plantilla = new plantilla($serv,$user,$pass,$base,$url,$sitio);
$conexion = mysqli_connect($serv,$user,$pass,$base);

if ($_POST) {
    $nombre = $Main->limpiar($_POST['nombre']);
    $email= $Main->limpiar($_POST['email']);
    if(isset($nombre) && !empty($nombre) && isset($email) && !empty($email)){
        $hash = md5($nombre.$email);
        $mysqli = $conexion;
        $porter = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM feed where username = '$nombre' or email = '$email'");
        if($porter->num_rows ==0){ 
        if($mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `feed` (username, email, hash) VALUES (\''.$nombre.'\', \''.$email.'\', \''.$hash.'\')')){
        die('1: <div class="dialog_box">Gracias por suscribirse a nuestro boletin</div>');
        }else{
        die('0: <div class="dialog_box">Ocurrió un error.</div>');
        }
        }else{
        die('0: <div class="dialog_box">Ya estas Sucrito.</div>');
        }
    }else{
        die('0: <div class="dialog_box">Por favor completa todos los campos</div>');    
    }


}else{
    echo "<h1>404</h1>";
}
```

config.php

```
//Inicio de sesión
@session_start();
//Mostramos errores
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
//Definimos timezone
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
define('ROOT_DIRECTORY', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');

//Datos MYSQL
 $serv = "localhost";
 $user = "angela";
 $pass = "1q2w3e";
 $base = "angela";

 //conectamos..
$conexion_temporal = mysqli_connect($serv,$user,$pass,$base);
mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
if(!$conexion_temporal){
    exit('<title>Error</title><body style="clear: both;background: #F6F6F6;padding: 2em 2em 1em;border: 1px solid #E7E7E7;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-o-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;"><h2 align="center" style="color:#222; font-size:25px; font-family:Century Gothic;">Error <br /><br />No se pudo establecer la conexi&oacute;n a la base de datos </h2></body>');
}

//Datos del sitio
$mysqli = $conexion_temporal;
$query = $mysqli->query('select * from config');
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){$url = $row['url'];       
$title = $row['title'];
$sitio = $row['sitio'];
$max_size = $row['max_size'];
$paypal = $row['email'];
}

//configuraciones extras
$PermitirImprecion = TRUE;
require(ROOT_DIRECTORY . '/libs/Main.class.php');
$Main = new Main($serv,$user,$pass,$base,$url,$sitio);

//json
function setJSON($data, $type = 'encode'){
        require_once('JSON.php');   // INCLUIMOS LA CLASE
        $json = new Services_JSON;  // CREAMOS EL SERVICIO
        if($type == 'encode') return $json->encode($data);
        elseif($type == 'decode') return $json->decode($data);            
    }
$pfooter='fCBEZXZlbG9wZWQgYnkgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZGF0dGFzb2x1dGlvbnMuY29tLm14
Lz9yZWY9c2l0ZV9hbmdlbGFtZWRpbmFfbXgiIHRhcmdldD0iYmxhbmsiPkRhdHRhIFNvbHV0aW9u
czwvYT4=';
$footer = base64_decode($pfooter);
```

Comment: are you sure your not altering it in feed.php

Comment: can you include config php?

Comment: yes ,added config.php

Comment: could it be that your server has register_globals = on ?